How to Enforce Sync Order in ArgoCD app of apps pattern?
I'm using the app of apps pattern in ArgoCD and I'm looking for a way to enforce a sync order between certain apps. Specifically, I want the strimzi app to be synced before my app containing the Kafka CR, and the minio-operator app to be synced before my app containing the Minio CR.
Is there an easy way to manage dependencies or sync order between apps in ArgoCD?
Here is a link to my argoCD configuration: https://github.com/astrolabsoftware/fink-cd/tree/v3.1.3-rc1/apps/templates
Thanks in advance!

Within an app, you can set sync waves https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-waves/

Yes, but can I use that to order startup for multiple apps?

I have added an issue in argocd repo: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/discussions/19712
